# JavaScript div ordering script bug (switches order of the two divs below)

Tags: javascript, list, web, onclick

Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/s4UQP/

^ Here is the best way to see the code and how it works with the divs

But here is the code anyway:

```
function move(from, to) {

document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '...';

from = parseInt(from,10);
to = parseInt(to,10);

tbc = document.getElementById(from);
before = document.getElementById(to);
containr = document.getElementById('alldivs');

neworder = 'Order: <select><option onclick="move(' + to + ',1)">1</option><option onclick="move(' + to + ',2)">2</option><option onclick="move(' + to + ',3)">3</option></select> <br><a href="#" onclick="move(' + to + ',' + (to - 1) + ')">Send up</a> | <a href="#" onclick="move(' + to + ',' + (to + 1) + ')">Send down</a><br><a href="#" onclick="move(' + to + ',1)">Bring to front (#1)</a> | <a href="#" onclick="move(' + to + ',4)">Send to back (#4)</a>';

document.getElementById(from).getElementsByClassName('order')[0].innerHTML = neworder;

document.getElementById(from).getElementsByClassName('number')[0].innerHTML = to;

tempdiv = document.createElement('div');
tmphtml = document.getElementById(from).innerHTML;
tempdiv.className = 'holder';
tempdiv.innerHTML = tmphtml;

n = 0;
npieces = 4;


if (from < to) {
    nochanges = to - from;
    fromone = from + 1;
    //alert(n+' '+to+' '+fromone);
    for (n = fromone; n <= to; n++) {

        //alert('down');
        idnum = parseInt(document.getElementById(n).id,10);
        //alert(idnum);
        document.getElementById(n).getElementsByClassName('number')[0].innerHTML = (idnum - 1);
        alert(document.getElementById(n).id);
        document.getElementById(n).id = (idnum - 1);

        //alert('down '+idnum+' to '+(idnum-1));
    }

}

if (from > to) {
    nochanges = from - to;
    totone = to + 1;


    for (n = to; n < from; n++) {
        //alert('n is '+n+' going to '+to+' ends at '+totone);
        //alert('up');
        idnum = parseInt(document.getElementById(n).id,10);
        //alert(idnum);
        document.getElementById(n).getElementsByClassName('number')[0].innerHTML = (idnum + 1);
        alert(document.getElementById(n).id);
        document.getElementById(n).id = (idnum + 1);

        //alert('up '+idnum+' to '+(idnum+1));
    }

}


//tempdiv.id = 'span'+to;
if (from > to) {
    containr.insertBefore(tempdiv, before);
}

if (from < to) {
    before = to + 1;
    containr.insertBefore(tempdiv, document.getElementById(before));
}

tbc.parentNode.removeChild(tbc);

tempdiv.id = to;

document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'done';

}
```

The script works as you move a block (or div) up or down, but when you try to move a different block (e.g. the one at the top), it just switches around the first two blocks beneath it.
Could anyone give me any advice?

I don't know whether it's because of the order that the script was done in, or if it's something else. It's been confusing me for some time, and I'd really appreciate it if someone could look through it and give me some advice.

(I don't want to code it in jQuery, this is really just me trying to learn more JavaScript by coding something. If it's not the most efficient, secure, whatever, it's still just something with which I'm trying to teach myself JavaScript.)

Thank you for reading. (Please don't edit the JS Fiddle itself, but rather post any edits/improvements here. Thank you.)

[Edit: I'm not really writing a cliche sci-fi, they're just example divs because I couldn't think of anything better]

Comment: check your HTML first, there seems to be a problem with <div> opening and closing tags not matching. Also, 1, 2, 3, 4 are not valid IDs, although that doesn't seem to be the thing that's preventing the script from working.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Stuart. I tried adding a </div> but it still doesn't work (the 2 divs below switching again, instead of the div moving down). I'll see what I can do with the div IDs; they seemed strange to me when I was coding the CSS, so I'll add a letter before them and split it with JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think either of those things is the main problem (see my answer below). I don't recommend using the IDs (with or without a letter at the start) to identify the position of each block - it just gets very confusing to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the statement `neworder =...` you change the values of the `onclick` functions, but you only do this for the block that is about to be moved. The problem is that the other blocks also change positions. For instance, if you click on 'Send up' for block 2, then block 2 moves up to position 1 and block 1 moves down to position 2. But only the event handlers on block 2 are updated accordingly. So the next time you click on (what was originally) block 1, it will not behave correctly.

One solution would be to update the event handlers on all of the blocks that are affected every time one of them is moved. For instance, make a function called `updateEventHandlers(blockNumber)` and call it for all of the affected blocks.

However relying on IDs to indicate the position of a block and then fiddling with the IDs after they are moved can lead to all sorts of confusion. It is better either to keep an array or dictionary recording the positions of the blocks, or loop through them to determine their positions in the DOM each time you want to move them.

For instance the following code provides moveup, movedown and moveto functions using the latter method (it finds where the element is in the DOM and swaps it with the holder before or after). ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mcWRb/4/))

```
function E(id) { return document.getElementById(id);}
var holders = document.getElementsByClassName('holder');
function moveup(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < holders.length - 1; i++) {
        // Find the holder before the one we're interested in
        if (holders[i + 1] == E(id)) {
            // Swap their positions
            E('alldivs').insertBefore(E(id), holders[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    resetNumbers();
}
function movedown(id) {
    for (var i = 1; i < holders.length; i++) {
        // Find the holder after the one we're interested in
        if (holders[i - 1] == E(id)) {
            // Swap their positions
            E('alldivs').insertBefore(holders[i], E(id));
            break;
        }
    }
    resetNumbers();
}
function moveto(id, position) {
    if (position == holders.length) {  // move to end
        E('alldivs').appendChild(E(id));
    }
    else {                       // move before another holder
        E('alldivs').insertBefore(E(id), holders[position - 1]);
    }
    resetNumbers();
}
function resetNumbers() {
    // Reset all the numbers to reflect their current position
    var numbers = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i].innerHTML = i + 1;
    }
}​
```

A few other points:

- clicking on the `select`s in your original code won't do anything initially, because no event handler is assigned to it until after one of the elements has been moved
- there is a missing `</div>` from the end of the html
- it is good practice to declare variables using `var` somewhere in your code
- appendChild and insertBefore remove a node from its current position in the DOM before appending/inserting it in its new position, so there is no need to remove the element explicitly.
- having moveup and movedown functions is better than only having moveto, which requires you to insert the current, preceding and following positions into the html and refresh them every time a block is moved.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you :) I really appreciate the time you put into this, and the added explanations to the code. Thanks again